# Ajax button in admin

Tags: ajax, 8

So I figured I'd create a configuration for my module. I created a normal form with some fields to let the users configure the module with variables. I also added a button which would do an ajax-call to a service. Problem is, this button is within the form, meaning it submits the form aswell.

```
$form['products']['update'] = array(
            '#type' => 'button',
            '#ajax' => array(
                'path' => '/products/update',
                'event' => 'click'
                ),
            '#value' => t('Update Products')
);
```

I just want the button to actually call this service (/products/update) and not act like a submit button. This worked in beta3 but is not an annoying feature in beta4, preventing the actual service call. How do I fix this?

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but converting the button to a styled link might be an easy solution

Comment: `button` types are not supposed to call the submit handlers. You will get the form values, but it shouldn't execute submit handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajax path is not supported anymore I think. It would need to be a route.

Why do you need a path? The common way to do this is to have a #submit callback on that form element, then just that will be called.

Comment: Well according to most tutorials out there setting up an AJAX-service in Drupal 8 is by using the path as a main-route and then the callback is there as a.. callback. That's the main reason why I used path this early. I will have to adapt, I suppose.

Comment: I'm not sure where you've seen those tutorials, but many D8 tutorials are out of date anyway, so careful with those. You can see the properties for #ajax for example on RenderElement::preRenderAjaxForm(), and it has 'url', which is a Url object. But almost nothing in core uses that, the common case is to use the standard url, which is system/ajax, which takes care of processing your form, submitting it as defined and then calling the callback.

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!core.api.php/group/ajax/8 I suppose this is outdated, but it can be confusing when path actually states being used for requests. Also since I am very used to setting up routes for services from other frameworks I thought this approach was the easiest.

Comment: Is there any workaround my initial solution to just have a button use the route 'products/update' through an AJAX request?

Comment: Yes, you could create a Url object with Url::fromRoute() or Url::fromUri() and assign that to 'url'.

Comment: Anyway you could help me out a little bit more with the code? :) Am trying to find information about the scenario but the help I find seems a tad outdated.

Comment: I did follow Berdirs suggestion and rewrote the code to use a callback instead. Calling the function immeditately instead of creating a route proved more useful.